If one profile of mix strategy is not Nash, then one player will deviate to a pure strategy?
Suppose that in one strategy profile of N-person game, everyone is playing a mixed strategy, and it is not in Nash Equilibrium.
Does this imply that there exist a player i who will be strictly better off by deviating to some pure strategy?

Yes, the implication is true

In general, pure strategies are not better than mixed ones, so the implication is not true. If pure strategies were better then we should find pure strategies at the equilibrium points. Pure strategies are particoular case of mixed strategies. Player i-th could be better off simply playing the mixed strategy and adopting the max strategy while other N-1 players play mixed strategy far to equilibrium.

Suppose $(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots, \sigma_N)$ is a mixed strategy profile that is not a Nash equilibrium. Therefore, there exists a player $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ such that $\sigma_i$ is not a Best response to $\sigma_{-i}$. Since $\sigma_i$ is not the Best Response to $\sigma_{-i}$, so there exists either a pure strategy $a_i$ of player $i$ such that the expected utility of player $i$ satisfy $U_i(a_i,\sigma_{-i})>U_i(\sigma_i,\sigma_{-i})$, or there exists another mixed strategy $\sigma_i'$ of player $i$ such that the expected utility satisfy $U_i(\sigma_i',\sigma_{-i})>U_i(\sigma_i,\sigma_{-i})$. In the latter case, when there exists a mixed strategy $\sigma_i'$, observe that $U_i(\sigma_i',\sigma_{-i})$ is the weighted average of the expected utility of actions in its support. So there must be at least one action $a_i'$ in the support of $\sigma_i'$ such that $U_i(a_i',\sigma_{-i})\geq U_i(\sigma_i',\sigma_{-i})>U_i(\sigma_i,\sigma_{-i})$. Therefore, we have shown that:  If we consider a mixed-strategy profile of N-person game that is not a Nash Equilibrium then there exist a player $i$ who will be strictly better off by deviating to some pure strategy.

Dear Amit, I believe that if you repeat the reasoning for all N players, you come to the conclusion that pure strategies are better for everyone! So, all players deviating to pure strategy get the best payment. In conclusion, they have reached an equilibrium point made of pures strategies. This is equivalent to saying that all equilibrium points are constituted by pure strategies. All Nash equilibria would consist of pure strategies and this is absolutely FALSE!

Dear Marco, We cannot conclude from my argument that all equilibrium are always in pure-strategies. There are mistakes in your argument.

@marcotognoli Consider matching pennies
\begin{array}{c|cc}
& \text{Heads} & \text{Tails} \
\hline
\text{Heads} & (1, -1) & (-1, 1) \
\text{Tails} & (-1, 1) & (1, -1) \
\end{array}
There is only a mixed-strategy equilibrium where both players choose their actions with a probability of 0.5 each, and there is no pure-strategy equilibrium. Notice, however, that given Player 1's equilibrium mixed strategy, Player 2 finds both actions to be best responses, including any mix of the two.

@marcotognoli In other words, in Matching Pennies, given that Player 1 plays a mixed strategy of choosing each action with a probability of 1/2, Player 2 is indifferent between playing the pure strategy Heads and the pure strategy Tails, as both yield the same expected utility of 0. Therefore, Player 2 has no reason to avoid playing a mixed strategy of choosing each action with a probability of 1/2, which will also result in an expected payoff of 0.

@Amit I think you got a brilliant answer. In my humble opinion you are right. However, if others get a contradictory answer, I might think again. Many thanks for your help!

Thanks for your example Amit, the property "can improve its payoff by deviating to a pure strategy" is sometimes true and sometimes false, depending on the structure of the game. It is not valid as a general statement, because there are games (like Matching Pennies you have mentioned) in which improvement is possible only through mixed strategies. Q.E.D. which was to be demonstrated: the implication
"If a strategy profile is not a Nash equilibrium, then there exists a player i who can improve his payoff by deviating towards a pure strategy" is not true in general.

@marcotognoli You write "because there are games (like Matching Pennies you have mentioned) in which improvement is possible only through mixed strategies." Please give an example of a mixed strategy profile that is not a NE for the Matching Pennies game and for which neither player can improve their payoff by deviating to a pure strategy.

@smcc Thanks for the suggestion, I provide a counterexample to what has been debated. We have to find a mixed strategy profile that: it is not a Nash equilibrium and no player can improve his payoff by deviating to a pure strategy. The profile (p = 0.6, q = 0.6) is not a Nash equilibrium and no player can improve his payoff by deviating towards a pure strategy. This is a specific case in which the property that a player "can improve by deviating towards a pure strategy" is false, despite being far from a Nash equilibrium.

@marcotognoli You have not provided a counterexample. If $p$ and $q$ are the probabilities of each player playing heads, then player $1$'s expected payoff from heads is $0.6(1)+0.4(-1)=0.2$ and the expected payoff from tails is $0.6(-1)+0.4(1)=-0.2$. Clearly player $1$ would be better off deviating to the pure strategy of heads than mixing over both heads and tails.

Let give a counterexample showing that player i who will be strictly better off by deviating to some pure strategy is in general false
We are going to introduce a game for which

The chosen mixed strategy profile is not a Nash equilibrium;
No player can improve his payoff by deviating to a pure strategy.

Let's define the two-player game A and B, with the following two strategies (options): "1" and "2".
The payoff matrix is:
Let give a counterexample showing that player i-th who will be strictly better off by deviating to some pure strategy is in general false.
Let's define the two-player game A and B having the following two strategies (options): 1 and 2.
The payoff matrix is




(B: 1)
(B: 2)




(A: 1)
(2, 2)
(1, 3)


(A: 2)
(3, 1)
(0, 0)



If both players play the following mixed strategies:

A plays 1 with probability p = 0.5 and 2 with probability 1-p = 0.5

Payoff for A $ = p \cdot \left(q \cdot 2 + (1-q) \cdot 1\right) + (1-p) \cdot \left(q \cdot 3 + (1-q) \cdot 0\right) = 0.5 \cdot \left(0.5 \cdot 2 + 0.5 \cdot 1\right) + 0.5 \cdot \left(0.5 \cdot 3 + 0.5 \cdot 0\right) = 1.5$
If A plays a pure strategy for 1, $p=1$, Payoff is = $q \cdot 2 + (1-q) \cdot 1 = 1.5$
If A plays a pure strategy for 2, $p=0$, Payoff is = $q \cdot 3 + (1-q) \cdot 0  = 1.5$

B plays 1 with probability q = 0.5 and 2 with probability 1-q = 0.5

Payoff for B $ = q \cdot \left(p \cdot 2 + (1-p) \cdot 3\right) + (1-q) \cdot \left(p \cdot 1 + (1-p) \cdot 0\right) = 1.5$
If B plays a pure strategy for 1, $q=1$, Payoff is = $p \cdot 2 + (1-p) \cdot 3 = 1.5$
If B plays a pure strategy for 2, $q=0$, Payoff is = $p \cdot 1 + (1-p) \cdot 0  = 0.5$
For both players:

Playing 1, 2, or the mixed strategy p = 0.5, q = 0.5 results in the same payoff 1.5
Neither player has an incentive to deviate to a pure strategy.

The mixed strategy profile p = 0.5, q = 0.5 is not a Nash equilibrium, as players can achieve a better payoff by choosing different mixed strategies.
This demonstrates that the claim "a player will always do strictly better by deviating to a pure strategy" is not true in general.

There are mistakes in your calculations. Please correct them. When B plays pure strategy of $1$, payoff is $2p+1(1-p)=1.5$ given that $p=0.5$. And when B plays pure strategy of $2$, payoff is $3p+0(1-p)=1.5$ given that $p=0.5$. Also observe that the mixed strategy profile you are considering is a mixed strategy Nash equilibrium. So this is not a valid counterexample.
